# Runtime-tests for the BGL

Tags: c++, testing, boost, boost-graph

The BGL provides concept checking for their graph concepts and it seems the header `boost/graph/graph_test.hpp` provides some kind of run-time checking for the given concepts but it has that scarry `UNDER CONSTRUCTION` at the beginning and is from 2002.

Are there other runtime test-suits for the BGL or is it safe to use (and how to) `graph_test.hpp`?

Comment: The code looks reasonable enough to try; I don't think there are any other general tests (there are tests for specific data types and algorithms).  This code appears to only be used to test `subgraph` and not generally in BGL.  What specifically are you trying to test?

Comment: @JeremiahWillcock My graph implementation is a little bit tricky and I would like to test for the invariants of MutableGraphs `remove_*` and `add_*` Those should be the same for every graph, so it would be nice to have them supplied by a library.

Comment: It looks like the tests in that file should do what you want, then.  You might also want to look at the concept checks in the test suite (the `*_cc.cpp` files in `libs/graph/test`) for testing that all the correct functions and traits exist.

Comment: @JeremiahWillcock The file includes `boost/test/minimal.hpp` which conflicts with the current way I use Boost.Test. I'll try to sort that out somehow. Meanwhile, you might want to add an answer with some hints about where to find testcode for the BGL so I can accept it.